# Wrong ObjectId in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a problem with Mongo DB. 
Somehow i have a wrong ObjectId in row entry. The ObjectId has an invalid length.

How can i force Mongo to delete that ObjectId ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ObjectId in MongoDB is a special 12-byte BSON datatype, which is designed to have a high probability of being unique when allocated (i.e.: generated based on current time, specific machine and so on).

You can check the validity of a given ID string, using a method provided by MongoDB driver. For example, in Java, you can use the following method:

```
static boolean isValid(String s)
```

in class:

```
org.bson.types.ObjectId
```

to check whether a given input string is a corrent ObjectId or not.

Hope this'll help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if I'm just not understanding this issue; but can't you simply do a :

```
db.collection.remove({"_id":"yourInvalidId"});
```

to remove the row then reinsert it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot update the _id field (it's a mongo limitation) you'll have to copy the row and delete the old one.
In the shell :

```
var row = db.yourcollection.findOne({_id : "your invalid id"})
db.yourcollection.remove({_id : "your invalid id"}))
row._id = new ObjectId()
db.yourcollection.insert(row)
```

However this is strange that you have an ill-lengthed ObjectIf, did you create it yourself ?

Comment: just an fyi; you're taking an extra step here.  You could do find and exclude the _id from it, and then when you insert the new row, it would auto create a new id.

Answer (score 0):

if you have any other field within that object just do the following:

`db.collection.remove({"fieldName":"fieldValue"})`

and then just re-add, this should be safer than doing an update to the field.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be occur when code has semantics errors. A row according to the objectId can be updated without removing it.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
                    query.put("_id", "your id");
                    DBObject dbObj = testCol.findOne(query);
                    BasicDBList Brand_children= (BasicDBList) dbObj.get("children");
                    Brand_children.add(itemBrand);
                    System.out.println(Brand_children);
                    testCol.save(dbObj);
```

And also it can be remove as above